# Using the Vimeo API, how do I replace all videos in a Vimeo album?

Tags: vimeo-api

Using curl, I'm trying to create a working Vimeo API call that replaces the videos in a Vimeo album with a different set of videos. ([The docs are here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/me#/albums).) I am successfully deleting the existing videos from the album but my new video info seems to be invisible to Vimeo. Vimeo responds with a 201 ("created") instead of the 200 I'm looking for.

Here is my curl command (with subs for actual data):

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer 123abc456def" -X PUT --data "videos=%2Fvideos%2F11111%2C%2Fvideos%2F22222%2C%2Fvideos%2F33333" "https://api.vimeo.com/me/albums/7777777/videos"
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and the Vimeo API docs & playground don't give me the answers I need. My questions and observations:

- Should I be url encoding the new video URIs (e.g. 11111,22222, etc)? I have also tried without url encoding and it made no difference. But then the 201 might be telling me it didn't get as far as handling my replacement URIs.
- a PUT is required for this operation. I have used PUT successfully to add a video to an existing album (in LiveCode, haven't tried it with curl)
- I got the same results when I tried this PUT in LiveCode. I moved the request to curl because more people are familiar with curl.

This is my first rodeo using the Vimeo API. It's a great, vast resource and I've had no problems working with it until this. I'm just stuck on this item and really need it to work!

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ancient, deprecated way of handling batch editing. I'm not sure how it still exists. We will move it to the proper batch creation standard in 3.4.

I think the existing system is supposed to be a comma separated list of video id's, so

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer 123abc456def" -X PUT --data "videos=11111%2C22222%2C33333" "https://api.vimeo.com/me/albums/7777777/videos"
```

is likely the proper request.

Comment: Thanks Dashron! You're right, I had to pass video IDs, not video URIs. That did it. The [Vimeo API docs](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/me/albums/%7Balbum_id%7D/videos) are wrong on this.

Comment: Nice find, I'll fix that now